# Javascript Script won't execute with my 'else if' statements

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am working on an assignment and I can not understand why my script will not execute when I put the `else if` in.

Here is what I have in my script currently...

```
//Declaring Variables

var intCurrentLatitude = new Number(0);         
var intCurrentLongitude = new Number(0);        
var intDestinationLatitude = new Number(0);     
var intDestinationLongitude = new Number(0);

//Prompting User to enter in values

intCurrentLatitude = prompt ("What is your current latitude in degrees? (-90 to 90)");
intCurrentLongitude = prompt ("What is your current longitude in degrees? (-180 to 180)");
intDestinationLatitude = prompt ("What is your destination's latitude in degrees? (-90 to 90)");
intDestinationLongitude = prompt ("What is your destination's longitude in degrees? (-180 to 180)");

//Else ifs

if (intCurrentLatitude <= intDestinationLatitude && intCurrentLongitude <= intDestinationLongitude)
{
    alert("Head North East");
}
else if (intCurrentLatitude <= intDestinationLatitude && intCurrentLongitude => intDestinationLongitude)
{
    alert("Head North West");
}
else
{
    alert("Land hoy!");
}
```

I have coding for South West and East as well but just left it out for this example. Anyways my problem is that when I just use `If (.......)` and `Else alert "land hoy"` my script will go through and prompt the user for inputs. However as soon as I put in just one of the `else if`s nothing runs. Am I missing something?

Comment: You don't have to initialize your variables to `new Number(0)`. Just use `var myvar = prompt('Whatever')`. Also note `new Number(0)` returns an object, not a number.

Comment: @RandomUser that's not how this site works. Downvotes are on content, not users. A user's rep should have no bearing on whether or not we should downvote or closevote.

Comment: @Rion, for future reference, you should be using some form of javascript validation, either in your editor, build process, or manually. jshint is probably the most common and can be found here: http://jshint.com Many editors now have the capability of having jshint integrated directly into the editor to make this process easier. By following the standards enforced by a validator, you code will end up being less error prone and more consistent.

Answer (score 1):

In the else-if statement:

```
intCurrentLongitude => intDestinationLongitude
```

The browser interprets => as an invalid assignment. Any greater than/less than operators need to go before the equals sign. The following is correct -

```
intCurrentLongitude >= intDestinationLongitude
```

Comment: Wow I feel sooooooo stupid. Thanks a lot guys. I knew it was something stupid like that. I just could not spot it. Thank you very much.

Comment: Good find. You beat me to it by mere seconds!

Comment: Thanks for the edit, trnelson. Also @Rion, check the Developer Console (Ctrl-Shift-I or F12, usually) next time. It will show you most errors in your code.

Comment: Probably another stupid question, I'm completely new to this (should be fairly obvious), my instructor never told us which text editor to use and I have just been using notepad to get by. Which would you recommend I get or look into?

Comment: There are already numerous posts on SO about just that topic. [Here's a search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=recommend+text+editor). Also, comments should focus on the question at hand, so open new questions or search for further advice. All that being said, Notepad++, Sublime Text, or TextWrangler are good beginner choices.